# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' How to fix this one?

Tags: php

I'm trying to initialize a function of CI in my native code.

```
$cipher->initialize(
        [
         'driver'=>'openssl',
         'key' => $key
        ]
     );
```

I'm getting an error of 
**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['**

Can I ask how to fix this?

Using Php 5.3.3

Comment: You're using a version of PHP that does not support new array initialization syntax

Comment: Depending on the Version of PHP you are using: `[]` may or may not work. Try: `$cipher->initialize(
        array(
         'driver'=>'openssl',
         'key' => $key
        )
     );` instead (since you are using ***PHP 5.3***).

Comment: Thanks for the answer Poiz.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> You are using PHP 5.3. The Array Initialization Construct: `[]` will not work. Instead, use  this approach:

```
    <?php

        $cipher->initialize(
                array(
                 'driver'=>'openssl',
                 'key' => $key
                )
        );
```

Answer (score 8):

Your PHP version doesn't support `[]` use `array()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `[]`, Use:

```
 <?php

        $cipher->initialize(
                array(
                 'driver'=>'openssl',
                 'key' => $key
                )
        );
```